# HTTPClient sends out two requests when using Basic Auth?

Tags: java, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been using HTTPClient version 4.1.2 to try to access a REST over HTTP API that requires  Basic Authentication. Here is client code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());
// Enable HTTP Basic Auth
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username, this.password));

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(this.proxyURI.getHost(), this.proxyURI.getPort());

httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

When I construct a `POST` request, like this:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://my/url");
request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/atom+xml; type=entry")); // required by vendor
request.setEntity(new StringEntity("My content"));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I see in [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) that there are two requests being sent. One without the `Authorization: Basic ...` header and one **with** it. The first one fails with a 401, as you would expect, but the second goes through just fine with a 201.

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I should make clear that I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808928/getting-unexpected-401-from-apache-httpclient-basic-auth), but as you can see I set the `AuthScope` the same way and it didn't solve my problem. Also, I am creating a new `HttpClient` every time I made a request (though I use the same `ConnectionManager`), but even if I use the same `HttpClient` for multiple requests, the problem still persists.

**EDIT 2:**

So it looks like what @LastCoder was suggesting is the way to do. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328694/99971) to another question. The problem stems from my lack of knowledge around the HTTP spec. What I'm looking to do is called "preemptive authentication" and the `HttpClient` [docs mention it here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html). Thankfully, the answer linked to above is a much shorter and cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I noticed the same thing happening when using soap-ui eventhough the credentials were specified.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is really normal behavior.  The client makes an http request not assuming any auth and is then told (via the 401) that basic auth is needed.  In theory basic auth could be done preemptively but other auth schemes (ex. digest) need additional negotiation

Comment: @seand You know I actually considered that, but I don't know if that's built into the HTTP protocol or something like that.

Comment: @devslab It's possible for an http client to send the basic auth header up front (@LastCoder mentions just how to do that).  I'm thinking HttClient didn't know that the server wanted basic auth.  You told it the creds up front but not the protocol.  If there's a way to tell it 'this is basic' auth it might cut out the extra hop.

Comment: Turns out @LastCoder found that it is part of the HTTP spec to act this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than using .setCredentials() why don't you just encode USERNAME:PASSWORD and add the authentication header with .addHeader()

Comment: I could do that, certainly, and I'll test to see if that makes a difference, but according the example code (http://bit.ly/wEsEhY) in the `HttpClient` repo, that's the way I should do it.

Comment: @daveslab - It's part of the http client spec to request the resource anonymously first and respond to the 401 with the Authorization header. If it weren't clients would be spamming web servers with Authorization header credentials the web server doesn't even need. It's just basic security best practice.

Comment: It's a brute-force solution but would make it harder to switch protocols if needed (ex. if the server changed to use digest auth)

Comment: @LastCoder's comment IS the answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

This means that your server/target endpoint is creating a new session for every client request. This forces every request of yours to go through a hand-shake, which means the clients first makes the call and realizes that it needs authorization, then it follows with the authorization. What you need to do is send the authorization preemptively as follows:

httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);

Just to understand the process you may log your client request headers, to give you an idea of what your client is sending and receiving:
See if this works.